# Unable to view the webview in android when it is rotated to 180 degree

Tags: android, webview

I have used webview to load images from sdcard it works fine but when i click a button to roatate the webview to 180 degrees the webview gets disappears but when i press it again the webview is visible.
I have tried using changing the layout_width and height prgrammatically at run time but it didn't works.

MY Xml:

```
<nidhinkumar.pencilruler.helper.MywebView
    android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    />
```

Code:

```
public class TeacherViewImage extends Activity{
TextView text,imagename,imagecount,done;
ImageButton btnback,rotate,landrotate;
Button draw,zoom,undo,redo,clear,rotatez;
float initialScale;
int position;
String[] filepath;
String[] filename;
MywebView wx;
Bitmap b;
FrameLayout frame;
ProgressDialog pg;
int count=0;
ImageView img;
int width,height;
float angle=0;
final Context context=this;
LayoutAnimationController animController;
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    wx.saveState(outState);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the state of the WebView
    wx.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.teacherview_newimage);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Get the position
    position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
    // Get String arrays FilePathStrings
    filepath = i.getStringArrayExtra("filepath");
    // Get String arrays FileNameStrings
    filename = i.getStringArrayExtra("filename");
    count=position+1;
    // Locate the TextView in view_image.xml
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imagetext);
    // Load the text into the TextView followed by the position
    text.setText(filename[position]);
    // Locate the ImageView in view_image.xml
    img=new ImageView(this);
    imagecount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sheetevalimagename);
    imagecount.setText("Page"+count);
    draw=(Button)findViewById(R.id.teacherbtndraw);
    zoom=(Button)findViewById(R.id.teacherbtnzoom);
    clear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.teacherbtnclear);
    undo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.teacherbtnundo);
    redo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.teacherbtnredo);
    rotatez=(Button)findViewById(R.id.teacherbtnorientation);
    done=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.teacherbtndone);
    frame=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frmlayout);
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    btnback=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.teacherviewimageback);
    btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(TeacherViewImage.this,TeacherCorrectMainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });



    //imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    pg=new ProgressDialog(TeacherViewImage.this);
    //rotate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.rotate);
    wx = (MywebView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    wx.setBackgroundColor(0);
    //wx.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      wx.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    //wx.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    WebSettings webSettings = wx.getSettings();
    //wx.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        wx.loadUrl("file:///" + filepath[position]);
    }
    wx.loadUrl("file:///" + filepath[position]);
    //wx.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    // picView.setOnClickListener();
    //wx.setInitialScale(68);
    wx.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    wx.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    wx.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    wx.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wx.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    wx.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    wx.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    //wx.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wx.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            TeacherViewImage.this.initialScale = wx.getScale();

        }
    });

    rotatez.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imagecount.setText("Rotation-Enabled");
            v.setSelected(!v.isSelected());
          //  wx.allowzooming=false;
          //  wx.allowdrawing=false;
        //    wx.onRotate();

            angle+=180;
            if(angle==180){
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams vc=wx.getLayoutParams();
                vc.height=width;
                vc.width=height;

                wx.setLayoutParams(vc);


            }

            wx.setRotation(angle);

          //  wx.setLayoutAnimation(animController);
        }
    });

    draw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imagecount.setText("Draw ");
            v.setSelected(!v.isSelected());
            wx.allowzooming=false;
            // wx.allowdrawing=true;
            wx.allowdrawing=v.isSelected();
            wx.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            wx.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            wx.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        }
    });
    zoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imagecount.setText("Zoom Enabled");
            v.setSelected(!v.isSelected());
            wx.allowdrawing=false;
            wx.allowzooming=v.isSelected();
            wx.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            wx.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            wx.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
            wx.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
            wx.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        }
    });
    undo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imagecount.setText("Undo");
            wx.onClickUndo();
        }
    });
    redo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imagecount.setText("Redo");
            wx.onClickRedo();
        }
    });
    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imagecount.setText("Page"+count);
            wx.reset();

        }
    });
    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showInputDialog();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: your question is realted to iOS or android'

Comment: it is android only not ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting this piece of code to your webView in `onCreate()`:

```
wx.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

If you want you can set it into your xml file like this:

```
<nidhinkumar.pencilruler.helper.MywebView
    android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layerType="software"
    />
```

Comment: This is connected with the hardware acceleration of views in android. When you put this little piece of code, you disable hardware acceleration and force the view to be repainted back again when activity has been rotated. More about this here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html and here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType(int, android.graphics.Paint)